# Flutter version management. error : -bash: fvm: command not found

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to install the flutter version manager to switch the flutter version among the different flutter projects.
I use the command to install the fvm - `pub global activate fvm`

but when I run the command on the terminal - `fvm help`
There is an error  `-bash: fvm: command not found`

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 26):

Your .pub-cache binaries are not yet added to your PATH variable, used by your terminal. Add path with the following command:

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"`

This is the location where fvm is installed. So by exporting this path to your PATH variable you should be able to get fvm working from anywhere in your terminal.

Answer (score 17):

If you installed fvm using pub and you already have it in your path but you are still getting the error, follow these steps:

1. run `dart pub cache repair` // You may get an error: Failed to precompile fvm:main:. Just ignore that for now.
2. run `dart pub global activate fvm`

Comment: I run it on terminal VS Code Windows, it's still showing the error message. But when when i run it on Windows PowerShell Admin, the program is work

Comment: @Miko Restart your VSCode. Your terminal needs to start a new session.

Comment: @Miko you just saved my day! I can't run it in git bash terminal, but it works like charm in PowerShell.

Answer (score 7):

you can do a

```
flutter clean
```

then when its done, run

```
dart pub global activate fvm
```

when it's done it should work now, close the current bash terminal and open a new one

Answer (score 3):

You must add the path to the fvm executable to the $PATH environment variable. After running "pub global activate fvm" you should have seen a warning with instructions on how to fix it. You can watch this: https://youtu.be/R6vKde1vIGQ
That will get you up and running.

Answer (score 0):

if use windows 10 or later add system properties -> Environment Variables -> Path -> `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin`

Answer (score 0):

First confirm if fvm.bat is executing successfully, you should have the folder already in environment variable PATH(%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin). If it is then for fvm to run in bash, instead of fvm.bat, you need to create a shortcut, a file named fvm with no extension, the containing folder should also exist in PATH variable, the file contains location to fvm.bat and ends with a whitespace and S*.